# Possibility of using Cordova with React-Native

Tags: cordova, react-native, cross-platform

I had this idea of developing cross-platform apps using Cordova with React-Native. Before coming here, I did my research but with not a single result. Is anyone out there that can give me a straight answer or at least a suggestion if it is possible to build an app using both Cordova and React-Native together?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can develop apps using `cordova` or `react-native` but you cannot combine both. I am attaching brief description of both so that you get and idea as these two frameworks have many differences

**React Native:**

React Native is based on React (a JavaScript framework) to design apps UI using JavaScript. It supports both Android and iOS to develop hybrid apps. Basically, React Native apps don’t use WebViews to render the app UI as in Cordova. A JavaScript interpreter is embedded to run only the JS code of the app.

**Cordova:**

Cordova is another open source JavaScript framework to design hybrid apps. Cordova apps use WebViews to render the user interface of the app. Cordova also allows developers to use latest web technologies like HTML5, JS, etc. to design apps for Android, iOS, and Windows.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Do you think it's possible to build components/packages/plugins that can later be used on both React-Native and Cordova platforms?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a possibility. They both use "bridges" to connect to their interface. So, you can built a bridge which could be used for both cases.

Comment: Thank you! I think the other guy gave me the exact explanation